# Umbraco Partial View Macro disappears from richtext editor when saving content

Tags: razor, macros, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-mvc

I'm struggling with a problem in Umbraco 7 that is when
I attach a macro from a Partial View Macro file inside my richtext editor, it disappears from the editor, when I save the content.
The content is displayed fine on the page, but when I save the content again, the macro also disappears from the webpage.

I don't have the problem if I insert a macro from a scripting file (placed in /macroScripts)

I've tried to search for a solution to this problem, but with no luck.

Hope some of you guys can help me out with this problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I just found out, that you cannot include a dash in your naming of the macro.
Mine was "Support-form".

I changed it to "SupportForm" and now it works :D!

And apparently, as a guy wrote, this also happens with white-spaces and no only dashes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Mine had a space in the alias.